# Not Able to click on button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added view with subview in Main.storyboard.

but While loading that view controller I have added that view in window. but I am not able to click on that view and its subview.
I have already make userinteractionenabled yes using storyboard.

here is my screen shot of that view

[image]

here is my viewdidload code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//Add Image View above window
UIWindow* currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[currentWindow addSubview:self.viewbgPopUp];
[currentWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
[self HidePopUp];
self.viewbgPopUp.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}
```

here is button done click method

```
  - (IBAction)MethodBtnDone:(id)sender
   {
     [self ShowOptionUploadImg];
   }
```

but I am not able to call this method while click on done method

appreciate for help

Comment: your are not able to click on done button right?

Comment: for that query you drag you done button in storyboard to last position

Comment: did you bind your action with UIButton corretly...?

Comment: just add it to self.view.window addSubView:yourview

Comment: After use self.view.window addsubview:youview . it is working fine but I want to display that view above navigation bar so that I have added it in window. @"Anil Solanki"

Answer (score 0):

You can add view on navigation controller's view. like below:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code. Remove `[currentWindow makeKeyAndVisible];` line of code

```
UIWindow* currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
self.viewbgPopUp.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[currentWindow addSubview:self.viewbgPopUp];
[currentWindow bringSubviewToFront:self.viewbgPopUp];
[self HidePopUp];
```

Hope it helps you...!

Answer (score 0):

Bring the subview to front.
[currentWindow bringSubviewToFront:self.viewbgPopUp